# Plot a line on a OHLC minutes graph by mpl_finance

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Using the below code, I can successfully plot a OHLC graph

```
names = pd.Series(data.index.strftime("%d-%m-%y").unique())
indexs = pd.Series(data.index.date).unique()

ohlc = data[data.index.date == indexs[0]].copy()

ohlc['mdate'] = [mdates.date2num(d) for d in ohlc.index]

ohlc['SMA10'] = ohlc["Close"].rolling(10).mean()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
mpl_finance.candlestick2_ohlc(ax,ohlc['Open'],ohlc['High'],ohlc['Low'],ohlc['Close'], width = 0.6)
xdate = ohlc.index
def mydate(x, pos):
    try:
        return xdate[int(x)]
    except IndexError:
        return ''
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(mydate))

fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

However, when I add this line
`ax.plot(ohlc.mdate, ohlc["SMA10"], color ="green", label = "SMA50")`, 
I can an empty graph with two vertical tine lines. What is wrong in here please?

[image]

```
                   Open    High     Low  ...    Volume          mdate  SMA10
Date_Time                                    ...                                
2018-02-13 11:55:00  7169.7  7172.4  7167.0  ...       444  736738.496528    NaN
2018-02-13 12:00:00  7171.6  7174.2  7164.2  ...       578  736738.500000    NaN
2018-02-13 12:05:00  7174.2  7174.7  7170.7  ...       458  736738.503472    NaN
2018-02-13 12:10:00  7172.0  7175.7  7171.2  ...       401  736738.506944    NaN
2018-02-13 12:15:00  7174.7  7176.7  7173.0  ...       389  736738.510417    NaN
```

This is the columns of my data

```
Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'mdate', 'SMA10'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: plot each series separately and observe the values on the x axis. From the plot it can be seen that one plot has datetime indexes while the other has something else. That's why it gets displayed on the far right

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
ax.plot(ohlc.mdate, ohlc["SMA10"], color ="green", label = "SMA50")
```

by

```
ax.plot(ohlc.index, ohlc["SMA10"], color ="green", label = "SMA50")
```

Comment: I have the following error after replacing mdates. ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (142,)

Comment: This is the new error. ValueError: view limit minimum -36837.26482638889 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

Comment: you must have somewhere your dates, from your example is really hard to know which variable has what type of data. ohlc.index shoould not be numeric for starters, if you're using date2num on it.

Comment: from the documentation of mpl_finance I can see that date handling is very particular, so makes sense this is giving you a lot of trouble

Comment: I have updated the question with more detail. Ohlc has index of type datetimeindex, and I have created mdate using date2num. I have checked out these examples already, but still can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: found something that may be useful for you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199532/plotting-moving-average-on-top-of-candlestick-chart

Comment: This gives me the initial result, plot with no error but two vertical lines.